# Robot keep mouse in window

Tags: java, input, mouse, lwjgl

I have a fps "camera", and just recently managed to set up mouse movement to rotate the angle of viewing. The one problem with the camera is that the mouse can leave the window and the angles will not rotate anymore. I know I can use a robot method like `mouseMove()`, however, I've heard that it makes the camera rotation feel very jerky. Is there any other way to keep the mouse in the window, say like, Minecraft? I'm using Minecraft as an example because my program uses LWJGL too, and I was wondering how Notch does it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Mouse.setGrabbed(true)` at a start-up moment,

and for every game-loop(frame):

catch mouse movement with `Y_Angle += Mouse.getDX()*0.1f`,

then rotate your view matrix around Y axis on `Y_Angle` degrees/radians.

For rotation around X and Z axes use `Mouse.getDY()` and think on your own how to implement right matrix rotation for those, but this is the *main idea*.